# unable to read xml node (content:encoded)

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to read the contents of node content:encoded in C#:

The xml is:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="http://site.com/images/image.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://site.com/image.jpeg"/></a></div></content:encoded>
```

I want to read the text "http://site.com/images/image.jpg" . First problem is reading inside content:encoded which involves somekind of namepsace issue which i am unable to resolve. Second problem how to read text inside the hyperlink?
The code i am trying:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(RSSXml.NameTable);

                    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("content", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

                    XmlNode node = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", namespaceManager);



                    MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Please start with valid sample - CDATA section is not closed in one you have...

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming something like this `<c:e><![CDATA[<a><b aa="bb" /> </a> ]]</c:e>` you need to read VALUE of the c:e node, load it as XML (or maybe in your case as HTML) and select whatever you need in resulting object.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Sample {
    static void Main(string[] args){
        string xmlCode = @"<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><div class=""separator"" style=""clear: both; text-align: center;""><a href=""http://site.com/images/image.jpg"" imageanchor=""1"" style=""clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;""><img border=""0"" src=""http://site.com/image.jpeg""/></a></div></div>]]></content:encoded>";
        xmlCode = @"<root xmlns:content=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">" + xmlCode + "</root>";
        var RSSXml = new XmlDocument();
        RSSXml.LoadXml(xmlCode);
        var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(RSSXml.NameTable);

        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("content", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

        XmlNode node = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("//content:encoded", namespaceManager);
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);//CDATA

        RSSXml.LoadXml(node.InnerText);
        namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(RSSXml.NameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
        var href = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:div/ns:a/@href", namespaceManager);
        Console.WriteLine(href.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second part, OK if you can interpret as XML.Otherwise requires the Parse as HTML.